# htaccess doesn't work as I expected

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following script:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# PATH
RewriteBase /bbv/

# ERROR RULE
ErrorDocument 404 /bbv/404.php

# WORKS
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ template_cat.php?cat=$1 [L]

# THIS DOES NOT WORK
RewriteRule ^(.*)\(.*)-(.*)$ template_prod.php?cat=$1&prod=$2&id=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ template_cat.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

And I want to be like: *localhost/bbv/**category*** and *localhost/bbv/**category/product-id***

Where is the mistake? tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
# ERROR RULE
ErrorDocument 404 /bbv/404.php    
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    
# PATH
RewriteBase /bbv/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# WORKS
RewriteRule ^home$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ template_cat.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^-]+)-(.+)$ template_prod.php?cat=$1&prod=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ template_cat.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: localhost/bbv/category <- this works, but this localhost/bbv/category/product-id is bad. (no css rules is loading)

Comment: css loading is due to your use of relative links. use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: tx, I have used <base href="localhost/bbv/" /> and now the only problem is 404 redirect ... Page not redirecting properly

Comment: It should be: `<base href="/bbv/" />` OR whatever your path is.

Comment: Same thing with "/bbv/"... but I think it's a conflict with this rule: **RewriteRule ^(.+)$ template_cat.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA]**  and works if this it's disabled.

Comment: Check in firebug which URL is causing 404?